# Additional authentication after using Windows Hello logon

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication

A client uses Windows 10 laptops linked to Microsoft 365/Azure for authentication. They use Windows Hello and therefore can logon and/or unlock using password, PIN, fingerprint or face. The laptop locks after 5 minutes of being idle. MFA is implemented but this only kicks in when logging into a new device/password changed etc.

This has been deemed not secure enough and they want to implement additional 2FA authentication via mobile phone. The requirement is simple - upon authenticating using Windows Hello (logon or unlock) and 24 hours has expired, require an additional authentication step via their mobile phone.

Is this possible? We've trial Duo and it sort of does this but forces the user to always use password, i.e. they lose the other Windows Hello authentication methods.

Comment: Windows doesn’t have a solution that requires authentication after you already authenticated your account. [FIDO2](https://www.yubico.com/authentication-standards/fido2/?source=pepperjam&publisherId=159404&clickId=4133499068&utm_source=pepperjam&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=159404) could be a solution but it probably won’t be compatible with Windows Hello

Comment: I suggest you get in touch with Microsoft. Or rather, get your higher ups in touch with Microsoft. MS will tell you/them why this isn’t a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @DanielB - I personally think it's OTT and I have pushed back to finance/legal. But they're telling me that in the UK, we'll not get the level of cyber insurance we need unless this is implemented.

I do think that we should encourage people when out of office/in public places to use fingerprint or face unlock instead of PIN/password. With the later somebody could watch you enter your PIN and steal it.

If course, they should contact IT immediately to get the account/laptop locked but doubt they will.